# necessary and sufficient conditions for linear elasticity

Tags: experimental-physics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, rheology

If it's experimentally observed that a particular elastic isotropic material has a linear relationship between stress and strain for a certain range of stresses and strains, does it follow that a linear elastic model would be appropriate for modeling this material?

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a material's stress-strain behavior to be approximated using linear elasticity?

Comment: Certainly if you remain within those limits. And likely it is fine extrapolating to lower stresses and strains (ignoring, e.g., creep). Extrapolating would be bad since you will hit plasticity or fracture or load rate issues (actually you could hit those even in low strain limits).

Comment: A linear relation between stress and strain does not guarantee that the material is linearly elastic in this region.  To be linearly elastic, you would have to be able retrace the strains as you ease up on the stress.

Comment: @JonCuster When you say load rate, are you referring to power where load is a reference to force? Chester appears to suggest that the material isn't guaranteed to be linearly elastic even if I should remain in this region.

Comment: Well, it is always good to understand that 'elastic' response can have small permanent deformation associated with it. But, in general, the strain rate (how fast you pull on the sample) will impact the measured stresses. You can have viscoelasticity, brittle failure at lower strains, etc.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Do we know the necessary and sufficient conditions for the applicability of a linear elastic model? I mean is there a set number of experimental tests required?

Comment: Well, to check linear, you just do a tensile stress-strain test.  To check elastic, you just retrace the test backwards and see if the stress-strain curve superimposes.

Comment: @ChesterMiller But, I thought there was an issue with the rate at which stress was applied? So I can't be certain that the linear model would be appropriate even for small stresses/strains given that there might be a non-linear dependence on the stress-rate . Would you agree?

Comment: The stress rate or strain rate is a factor only if the material is viscoelastic.

Comment: @ChesterMiller So it follows that tests for viscoelastic properties are necessary as a material linear stress-strain curve and still be viscoelastic. Would you agree?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  For a viscoelastic material, the stress-strain curve depends on how fast you are deforming the material, and the stress-strain curve will probably not be linear, although, doubling the strain rate of a viscoelastic material will often double the stress at each strain.  In this sense, the behavior can be considered linear.

Comment: @ChesterMiller When you say 'probably not' do you know the approximate probability? I mean is it not possible that the stress-strain curve is actually linear?

Comment: It is possible for the stress-strain curve to be linear if the viscous contribution in negligible, or of the strain rate is adjusted in just the right way (depending on the rheological characteristics of the actual material).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your 1st question is a trivial "Yes."  If testing the material shows that stress is proportional to strain within the range of interest, then it is obvious that a linear model is appropriate.  Why would you think otherwise?  What other answer could be given?

In your 2nd question, you are trying to apply strict mathematical criteria in the context of experimental physics.  I do not think that it is possible or useful or desirable to do so.

It would be extremely difficult to specify "necessary and sufficient" conditions which apply in all cases.  Materials differ widely in their properties.  Experiments differ in their purposes and their requirements for accuracy.  Whether the use of any  model is justified depends very much on the particular circumstances - eg the relation between the model and the other parts of the experiment - and is largely a matter of judgement.  Instead of "necessary and sufficient" physicists, like engineers, use more subjective criteria such as "reasonable" and "appropriate".

I would think that there is the same difficulty within experimental mathematics.